# failed to change the color theme in org mode by using `face-remap-add-relative`

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use a `calm-forest` color theme in general. But I want to use a light theme when I edit the `org` file. Thus I rewrote the `emacs-21` color theme to a hook as the following scripts, but I failed to get a correct color scheme (seems the opacity of all colors decreases).

What happened to my script? How do I change the `org` file to the correct `emacs-21` color theme?

```lisp
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path
         (file-name-as-directory "~/syncthing/emacs/replace-colorthemes/"))

(load-theme 'calm-forest t t)
(enable-theme 'calm-forest)


(defun my-org-mode-faces-emacs-21 ()
  ;; (face-remap-add-relative  'default :background "white" :foreground "black")
  (face-remap-add-relative  'default  '(:background "white" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'mouse  '(:background "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cursor  '(:background "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'border  '(:background "black"))

  (face-remap-add-relative  'Man-overstrike-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'Man-underline-face  '(:inherit default :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-here-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-invalid-face  '(:inherit default :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-pod-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Firebrick"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-pod-head-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'gnus-article-button-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'gnus-article-mouse-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'gnus-mouse-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'help-highlight-face  '(:inherit default :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'idlwave-class-arrow-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'idlwave-shell-breakpoint-face  '(:inherit default :background "Pink" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'idlwave-shell-expression-face  '(:inherit default :background "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'idlwave-shell-stop-line-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ispell-highlight-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'list-matching-lines-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'view-highlight-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-mouse-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'Info-title-1-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold  :height 1.728))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'Info-title-2-face  '(:inherit default :bold t  :weight bold :height 1.44))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'Info-title-3-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold  :height 1.2))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'Info-title-4-face  '(:inherit default :bold t  :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'antlr-font-lock-keyword-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "black" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'antlr-font-lock-literal-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "brown4" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'antlr-font-lock-ruledef-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'antlr-font-lock-ruleref-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "blue4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'antlr-font-lock-tokendef-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'antlr-font-lock-tokenref-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "orange4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'bold  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'bold-italic  '(:inherit default :italic t :bold t :slant italic :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'calendar-today-face  '(:inherit default :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-acknowledgement-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Firebrick"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-conditionals-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-date-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-email-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-file-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-function-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-list-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Purple"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'change-log-name-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "CadetBlue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'comint-highlight-input  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'comint-highlight-prompt  '(:inherit default :foreground "dark blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-array-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :background "lightyellow2" :foreground "Blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-hash-face  '(:inherit default :italic t :bold t :background "lightyellow2" :foreground "Red" :slant italic :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cperl-nonoverridable-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "chartreuse3"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-button-face  '(:inherit default :background "lightgrey" :foreground "black"
                                :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-button-pressed-face  '(:inherit default :background "lightgrey" :foreground "black"
                                    :box (:line-width 2 :style pressed-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-changed-face  '(:inherit default :background "blue" :foreground "white"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-comment-face  '(:inherit default :background "gray85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-comment-tag-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "blue4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-documentation-face  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-face-tag-face  '(:inherit default :bold t  :weight bold :height 1.2))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-group-tag-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue" :weight bold :height 1.2))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-group-tag-face-1  '(:inherit default :bold t  :foreground "red" :weight bold :height 1.2))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-invalid-face  '(:inherit default :background "red" :foreground "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-modified-face  '(:inherit default :background "blue" :foreground "white"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-rogue-face  '(:inherit default :background "black" :foreground "pink"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-saved-face  '(:inherit default :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-set-face  '(:inherit default :background "white" :foreground "blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-state-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "dark green"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-variable-button-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :underline t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'custom-variable-tag-face  '(:inherit default :bold t  :foreground "blue" :weight bold :height 1.2))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-filename-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "blue4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-handled-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "pink"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-header-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue4" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-marked-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "green3" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-msg-face  '(:inherit default :italic t :slant italic))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-need-action-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "orange"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'cvs-unknown-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diary-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-added-face  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-changed-face  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-context-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "grey50"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-file-header-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :background "grey70" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-function-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "grey50"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-header-face  '(:inherit default :background "grey85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-hunk-header-face  '(:inherit default :background "grey85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-index-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold :background "grey70"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-nonexistent-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold :background "grey70"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'diff-removed-face  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-boring  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-directory  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-executable  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-flagged  '(:inherit default :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-marked  '(:inherit default :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-permissions  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-setuid  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-socket  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'dired-face-symlink  '(:inherit default :foreground "Purple"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-default-face  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-file-name-face  '(:inherit default :italic t :slant italic))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-member-attribute-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-member-class-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "purple"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-progress-face  '(:inherit default :background "blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-root-class-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ebrowse-tree-mark-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-current-diff-face-A  '(:inherit default :background "pale green" :foreground "firebrick"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-current-diff-face-Ancestor  '(:inherit default :background "VioletRed" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-current-diff-face-B  '(:inherit default :background "Yellow" :foreground "DarkOrchid"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-current-diff-face-C  '(:inherit default :background "Pink" :foreground "Navy"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-even-diff-face-A  '(:inherit default :background "light grey" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-even-diff-face-Ancestor  '(:inherit default :background "Grey" :foreground "White"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-even-diff-face-B  '(:background "Grey" :foreground "White"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-even-diff-face-C  '(:inherit default :background "light grey" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-fine-diff-face-A  '(:inherit default :background "sky blue" :foreground "Navy"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-fine-diff-face-Ancestor  '(:inherit default :background "Green" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-fine-diff-face-B  '(:inherit default :background "cyan" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-fine-diff-face-C  '(:inherit default :background "Turquoise" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-odd-diff-face-A  '(:inherit default :background "Grey" :foreground "White"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-odd-diff-face-Ancestor  '(:inherit default :background "light grey" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-odd-diff-face-B  '(:inherit default :background "light grey" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'ediff-odd-diff-face-C  '(:inherit default :background "Grey" :foreground "White"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-archive-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Orchid" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-backup-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "OrangeRed"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-clutter-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "OrangeRed" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-directory-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-executable-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "ForestGreen" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-missing-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-product-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "OrangeRed"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-readonly-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Brown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-special-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Magenta" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-symlink-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Dark Cyan" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-ls-unreadable-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Grey30"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-prompt-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-test-failed-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "OrangeRed" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'eshell-test-ok-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Green" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'excerpt  '(:inherit default :italic t :slant italic))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'fixed  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'fixed-pitch  '(:inherit default :family "courier"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'flyspell-duplicate-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Gold3" :underline t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'flyspell-incorrect-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "OrangeRed" :underline t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-builtin-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Orchid"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-comment-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Firebrick"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-constant-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "CadetBlue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-doc-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-doc-string-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-function-name-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-keyword-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Purple" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-preprocessor-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "CadetBlue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-reference-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Orchid"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-string-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-type-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "ForestGreen" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-variable-name-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'font-lock-warning-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'fringe  '(:inherit default :background "grey95"))

  (face-remap-add-relative  'header-line  '(:inherit default :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button) :background "grey90" :foreground "grey20" :box nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-black-b  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-black-hb  '(:inherit default :bold t  :weight bold :height 1.67))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-blue  '(:inherit default :background "light blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-blue-b  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-green  '(:inherit default :background "green"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-green-b  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "green" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-pink  '(:inherit default :background "pink"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-red-b  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'hi-yellow  '(:inherit default :background "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'highlight  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'highlight-changes-delete-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'highlight-changes-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'holiday-face  '(:inherit default :background "pink"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'idlwave-help-link-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'idlwave-shell-bp-face  '(:inherit default :background "Pink" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'info-header-node  '(:inherit default :italic t :bold t :weight bold :slant italic :foreground "brown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'info-header-xref  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold :foreground "magenta4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'info-menu-5  '(:inherit default :foreground "red1"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'info-menu-header  '(:inherit default :bold t  :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'info-node  '(:inherit default :italic t :bold t :foreground "brown" :slant italic :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'info-xref  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "magenta4" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'isearch  '(:inherit default :background "magenta4" :foreground "lightskyblue1"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'isearch-lazy-highlight-face  '(:inherit default :background "paleturquoise"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'italic  '(:inherit default :italic t :slant italic))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'log-view-file-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :background "grey70" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'log-view-message-face  '(:inherit default :background "grey85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'makefile-space-face  '(:inherit default :background "hotpink"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'menu  '(nil))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-cited-text-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-cc-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "MidnightBlue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-name-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "cornflower blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-newsgroups-face  '(:inherit default :italic t :bold t :foreground "blue4" :slant italic :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-other-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "steel blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-subject-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "navy blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-to-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "MidnightBlue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-header-xheader-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-mml-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "ForestGreen"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'message-separator-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "brown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'mode-line  '(:inherit default :background "grey75" :foreground "black" :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'mode-line-buffer-id  '(:inherit default :bold t :background "grey75" :foreground "black" :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'mode-line-mousable  '(:inherit default :background "grey75" :foreground "black" :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'mode-line-mousable-minor-mode  '(:inherit default :background "grey75" :foreground "black" :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'primary-selection  '(:inherit default :background "lightgoldenrod2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'reb-match-0  '(:inherit default :background "lightblue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'reb-match-1  '(:inherit default :background "aquamarine"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'reb-match-2  '(:inherit default :background "springgreen"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'reb-match-3  '(:inherit default :background "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'region  '(:inherit default :background "lightgoldenrod2"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'scroll-bar  '(:inherit default :background "grey75"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'secondary-selection  '(:inherit default :background "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'sh-heredoc-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "tan"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'show-paren-match-face  '(:inherit default :background "turquoise"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'show-paren-mismatch-face  '(:inherit default :background "purple" :foreground "white"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'show-tabs-space-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'show-tabs-tab-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'smerge-base-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'smerge-markers-face  '(:inherit default :background "grey85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'smerge-mine-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'smerge-other-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "darkgreen"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'speedbar-button-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "green4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'speedbar-directory-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "blue4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'speedbar-file-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "cyan4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'speedbar-highlight-face  '(:inherit default :background "green"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'speedbar-selected-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'speedbar-tag-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "brown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'strokes-char-face  '(:inherit default :background "lightgray"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-black  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-blackbg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "black" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-blue  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-bluebg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "blue" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-bold  '(:inherit default :bold t :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-cyan  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "cyan"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-cyanbg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "cyan" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-default  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-default-bg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-default-bg-inv  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-default-fg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-default-fg-inv  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-green  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "green"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-greenbg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "green" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-invisible  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-invisible-inv  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-magenta  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "magenta"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-magentabg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "magenta" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-red  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-redbg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "red" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-underline  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-white  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "white"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-whitebg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-yellow  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "yellow"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'term-yellowbg  '(:inherit default :stipple nil :background "yellow" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'tex-math-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "RosyBrown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'texinfo-heading-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'tool-bar  '(:inherit default :background "grey75" :foreground "black"
                          :box (:line-width 1 :style released-button)))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'tooltip  '(:inherit default :background "lightyellow" :foreground "black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'trailing-whitespace  '(:inherit default :background "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'underline  '(:inherit default :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vcursor  '(:inherit default :background "cyan" :foreground "blue" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-attribute-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Orchid"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-directive-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "CadetBlue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-enumvalue-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Gold4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-function-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Orchid4"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-prompt-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Red" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-reserved-words-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "Orange" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-font-lock-translate-off-face  '(:inherit default :background "LightGray"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-architecture-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-architecture-selected-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Blue" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-configuration-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-configuration-selected-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "DarkGoldenrod" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-instantiation-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Brown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-instantiation-selected-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Brown" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-package-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Grey50"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'vhdl-speedbar-package-selected-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "Grey50" :underline t))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'viper-minibuffer-emacs-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'viper-minibuffer-insert-face  '(:inherit default :background "pink" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'viper-minibuffer-vi-face  '(:inherit default :background "grey" :foreground "DarkGreen"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'viper-replace-overlay-face  '(:inherit default :background "darkseagreen2" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'viper-search-face  '(:inherit default :background "khaki" :foreground "Black"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-button-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-button-pressed-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "red"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-documentation-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "dark green"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-field-face  '(:inherit default :background "gray85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-inactive-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "dim gray"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'widget-single-line-field-face  '(:inherit default :background "gray85"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'woman-addition-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "orange"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'woman-bold-face  '(:inherit default :bold t :foreground "blue" :weight bold))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'woman-italic-face  '(:inherit default :italic t :foreground "red" :underline t :slant italic))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'woman-unknown-face  '(:inherit default :foreground "brown"))
  (face-remap-add-relative  'zmacs-region  '(:inherit default :background "lightgoldenrod2"))
  )
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-faces-emacs-21)
```

- themes I modified:

[image]

- correct emacs 21 themes:

[image]